# Load methods on bootup, Aurelius Titan with Rexster

Tags: methods, startup, gremlin, titan, rexster

Is there a way to load gremlin methods into the rexster/Titan on bootup?

This way I don't have to resend these methods each time I want to use them via rexpro. Currently I do stuff like this (trivial example):

```
rexpro_client.execute("def some_method(a){a.outE.count()}\n some_method("+some_variables+");")
rexpro_client.execute("def some_method(a){a.outE.count()}\n some_method("+some_variables2+");")
....
```

Which is obviously not efficient when executing this multiple times.

For extra clarification: I would obviously like to have my `some_method` pre-defined so I could simply do this in stead:

```
rexpro_client.execute("some_method("+some_variables+");")
rexpro_client.execute("some_method("+some_variables2+");")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Rexster Configuation](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Rexster-Configuration).

> The `<init-scripts>` element defines one or more comma-separated script files that gets executed at the initialization of a Gremlin Script Engine. The initialization allows for the creation of user-defined steps and functions to be made available.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Great! Do you know what the relative path of the init-scripts is? When it says `config/some_script.groovy`, is that relative to the xml-file, the rexster ssh, the terminal starting the server ..?

Comment: I mean "rextser sh script", not ssh.